# How to add a class to specific html elements created by ngRepeat?

Tags: angularjs

I need to add a class to the last `<li>` in an `<li>`group created using Angular's **ngRepeat**. So the code below

```
<ul>
  <li class="columns small-3" ng-repeat="tag in tags">
    {{tag}}
  </li>
<ul>
```

creates something like

```
<ul>
  <li>Art</li>
  <li>Science</li>
  <li>Beauty</li>
<ul>
```

What I need is for the class `.end` to be added to the last `<li>` so the end result would be

```
<ul>
  <li>Art</li>
  <li>Science</li>
  <li class="end">Beauty</li>
<ul>
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a combination of [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and [`$last`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

```
<ul>
  <li class="columns small-3" ng-class="{'end':$last}" ng-repeat="tag in tags">
    {{tag}}
  </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Is there also a way to do it based on the content of the `<li>`?

Comment: You can add any expression to `ng-class`. Just replace `$last` with whatever you want... E.g. `ng-class="{'end':tag == 'Lorem Ipsum'}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try with ng class with a condition on the  index